# Turn Off Debug mode @Vaadin Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

My issue is that my Vaadin application stuck at Debug mode and I can't turn it off.

```
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
In order to run your application in production mode and disable debug features, you should enable it by setting the servlet init parameter productionMode to true.
See https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html for more information about the production mode.
```

Even if I try to run with -Dvaadin.productionMode or -Pproduction  jvmArguments its always run in DEBUG mode...

I followed the link below and the pom file looks good

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <jvmArguments>-Dvaadin.productionMode</jvmArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

The application.properties file also contains that this is production.

```
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true

vaadin.servlet.heartbeatInterval=60

vaadin.servlet.closeIdleSessions=true
```

Full pom file: 
*Note: the end of profiles was commented out recently

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vaadin.tutorial.crm</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-crm</artifactId>
    <name>Vaadin CRM</name>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <vaadin.version>14.1.5</vaadin.version>

        <drivers.dir>${project.basedir}/drivers</drivers.dir>
        <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility 
                    mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ***************************** -->
        <!-- END OF SKELETON DEPENDIENCIES -->
        <!-- ***************************** -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed 
                    the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout. -->
                <configuration>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in package.json 
                and main.js files. It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <jvmArguments>-Dvaadin.productionMode</jvmArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

<!--        <profile> -->
<!--            <id>integration-tests</id> -->
<!--            <build> -->
<!--                <plugins> -->
<!--                    <plugin> -->
<!--                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                        <executions> -->
<!--                            <execution> -->
<!--                                <id>start-spring-boot</id> -->
<!--                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> -->
<!--                                <goals> -->
<!--                                    <goal>start</goal> -->
<!--                                </goals> -->
<!--                            </execution> -->
<!--                            <execution> -->
<!--                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id> -->
<!--                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase> -->
<!--                                <goals> -->
<!--                                    <goal>stop</goal> -->
<!--                                </goals> -->
<!--                            </execution> -->
<!--                        </executions> -->
<!--                    </plugin> -->

<!--                    Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
<!--                    <plugin> -->
<!--                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
<!--                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                        <executions> -->
<!--                            <execution> -->
<!--                                <goals> -->
<!--                                    <goal>integration-test</goal> -->
<!--                                    <goal>verify</goal> -->
<!--                                </goals> -->
<!--                            </execution> -->
<!--                        </executions> -->
<!--                        <configuration> -->
<!--                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace> -->
<!--                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions> -->
<!--                            <systemPropertyVariables> -->
<!--                                Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->
<!--                                <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver> -->
<!--                            </systemPropertyVariables> -->
<!--                        </configuration> -->
<!--                    </plugin> -->

<!--                    <plugin> -->
<!--                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId> -->
<!--                        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                        <version>1.0.17</version> -->
<!--                        <configuration> -->
<!--                            <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true -->
<!--                            </onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem> -->
<!--                            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory> -->
<!--                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver -->
<!--                            </rootStandaloneServerDirectory> -->
<!--                            <downloadedZipFileDirectory> -->
<!--                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver_zips -->
<!--                            </downloadedZipFileDirectory> -->
<!--                            <customRepositoryMap> -->
<!--                                ${project.basedir}/drivers.xml -->
<!--                            </customRepositoryMap> -->
<!--                        </configuration> -->
<!--                        <executions> -->
<!--                            <execution> -->
<!--                                use phase "none" to skip download step -->
<!--                                <phase>${drivers.downloader.phase}</phase> -->
<!--                                <goals> -->
<!--                                    <goal>selenium</goal> -->
<!--                                </goals> -->
<!--                            </execution> -->
<!--                        </executions> -->
<!--                    </plugin> -->
<!--                </plugins> -->
<!--            </build> -->
<!--        </profile> -->

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: The profile is used when you build the application with mvn package. How do you run the application?

Comment: 1) Do you actually have the `profile` "production"` active when you package/install it with maven? (you say you "run" it with the profile, but do you have it active when packaging/installing?) 2) your [vaadin properties are outdated](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-all-vaadin-properties.html#all-vaadin-configuration-properties) - there is no more `.servlet` in the middle